# Does GIT supports mirroring or proxy concept?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm new to GIT environment, so kindly bear with me :) 
In our project we are planning to move to GIT from RTC , and the code is shared as a tarball via ftp.
The tricky situation is , we are having our office at 2 different places . we will create a GIT server , say at location A and complete the code migration/import @ A and  later setup an exact setup @ B and subsequently synchronizing A to B’s GIT environment. (mirroring A to B and making B as master) . Is this approach feasible ? if so, during the process what are precautions we should incorporate like permission issues etc.(I understand , it doesn’t server the DVCS purpose of GIT, but still , like to know )

Also, if the above approach if possible , can it be executed via GitLab ?

Thanks!

Comment: Once you have A and B, does RTC still play any role in the situation you are describing?

Comment: @VonC : Nope , now its w.r.t to GIT.. as the source code is shared as a zip at  ftp location.

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment but the explanation is too long, so here goes.

Git is basically a distributed system, where changes are `push`-ed and `pull`-ed between repositories. Every 'checkout' or 'clone' is a copy of the entire repository, and there isn't really such a thing as the 'central repository'. At best there is an agreement as to which repository is central.

First you set up an empty GitLab repository A. 
You then `clone` it into a working environment W: `git clone git@gitlab.localnet:path/to/repo.git`  (gitlab explains this),
or, alteratively, create a new local repository, and add the remote:

```
    mkdir W && cd W
    git init
    git remote add A git@gitlab.localnet:path/to/repo.git
    git pull
```

You then add the files from your tarball, `commit` (to W), and `push` it back to your gitlab instance A.

If you want to sync to site B, you could use that same repository W, and register a second remote repository B (`git remote add B git@....`).
You can then simply `git push B`.

In short, you'll need a third working repository, `pull`-ing the changes from A and `push`-ing them to B.

I'm not familiar with RTC, but I am with several others, such as Subversion, which allows you to specify read/write permissions on any part of a repository (even branches). Git however does not have a permission system. You'd configure that on a per-repository level using GitLab. 
This means, that if your RTC permission scheme includes different permissions on a per project basis, you will now have to create a separate repository for each project.

There are a lot of ins and outs to this so I can recommend spending some time with the documentation before making such a transition.